# How to check if a CD-ROM is real or virtual

Tags: windows, wmi, wmi-query

I am using the following WMI query to enumerate the CD/DVR drives on my machine:

```
select * from Win32_CDROMDrive
```

Question: Is there any way I can detect which of the drives returned are actual, physical CD/DVD drives and which are virtual (e.g. Deamon Tools, MagicDisc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way, it's the aim of daemon-tools and these kind of software.

Maybe if you can manage to get the constructor or the brand of each CDROM drive, you could always look if it is "Daemon tools inc.".